# Using smart_pointer and set_new_handler together

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

Do one need to worry about using set_new_handlers in conjunction with smart or auto pointer's or the libraries come packed with handlers with refined error handling?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smart pointers that come with C++ (currently just `auto_ptr`, but soon including `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`) all use `new` by default, so they'll interface with the global new handler automatically.  You don't need to do anything special to ensure that the new handler is invoked when using these classes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Will it be a core dump if alloc exception occurs or a much refined message?Ta.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that auto_ptr never throws because it never allocates memory.  In the case of shared_ptr I believe that it just throws a bad_alloc exception if memory can't be found (even after calling the new handler).  That way, you can try to recover from the error, as is the default behavior when allocation fails in C++.

Comment: `std::smart_ptr` lets you specify an allocator, so you don't *have* to use the default allocator (which in turn is not required to be the "new" allocator, though it usually is).

Comment: Meaning if I want to customise the message, I could implement an override function and pass it to set_new_handler!?

Comment: You could do this, but I'd strongly suggest not doing it this way.  Instead, just put a try/catch statement around where you allocate memory and print a specialized error message for when the error actually occurs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're worrying about unrelated things. The new handler is a detail that specifies how `operator new` operates in the event that it cannot find enough memory to allocate. A smart pointer is a library-provided container class. Most C++ standard library containers need to allocate memory, which they do in a modular fashion by means of an allocator class. The default allocator may (and usually does) use `new` to obtain memory, but the process of memory allocation and object construction is decoupled, and there's nothing in any library class that needs to know any details of how the `new` operator works, and vice versa.

So whatever you do to your `new` operator (e.g. by installing handlers) will transparently work for standard library constructions, and there is nothing either side has to know about the other.